# How to get the elements of a Redis set that do NOT match a global key?

Tags: redis

How do I get all keys that do NOT have a corresponding global hash?

I store my main data in hashes with unique keys like so:

```
person_1: name: Anna, gender: female
person_2: name: Mark, gender: male
person_3: name: Pat, gender: female
person_4: name: Jo, gender: female
person_5: name: Robert, gender: male
```

Let's say I maintain an index of all male persons as a SET, like so:

```
male_persons: 2, 5, 6
```

As you can see, I snuck in an "error", as there is no person_6. Doing a SORT, I can easily build a "relational query" that gives me all males:

```
SORT "male_persons" BY nosort GET # GET "person_*->name"
```

Expected output is something like this:

```
"2", "Mark",
"5", "Robert",
"6", nil
```

My question is, how can I get in 1 or 2 queries to only the SET keys that have NO corresponding person, i.e. how do I produce only this line in the above example:

```
"6", nil
```

or even better:

```
"6"
```

or:

```
person_6
```

In SQL, this would be something like:

```
SELECT id FROM male_person_index WHERE male_person_index.id NOT IN (SELECT person.id FROM person);
```

I know one way of doing this would be to write a Lua script, but this seems so basic that it should be possible to do this in 1 or 2 standard queries, and I am just missing it. In this particular case performance is not super essential, so 1 or 2 or even 3 standard queries issued one after another should suffice.

**Update: I wrote a solution as a Lua script, but as stated before, I am not happy with it:**

```
eval 'local out = {}; local i = 1; local exists; for _, key in ipairs(redis.call("SMEMBERS", KEYS[1])) do exists = redis.call("EXISTS", "persons_" .. key); if exists == 0 then out[i] = key .. " -> " .. exists; i = i + 1; end; end; return out;' 1 "male_persons"
```

Reason I am unhappy is that this is "loopy" and slow and calls `EXISTS` potentially thousands or millions of times. I still believe this should be done in 2 or 3 transactions, not with 1000s or millions.

An elegant solution would take the output array of the `SORT` command, `STORE` it, and then somehow subtract from that result another query result array, in one swoop, to reduces the final output by the keys that are NOT orphaned, giving me, in the end, the orphan keys only.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following really really tricky way:

**Solutoin**

1. Use your sort solution and store the result into a list: *list1*.

   ```
   SORT "male_persons" BY nosort GET # GET "person_*->name" store list1
   ```
2. Sort *male_persons* by *person_*->name* in lexicographically order (i.e. `ALPHA` option), and store the result into a list: *list2*:

   ```
   SORT "male_persons" BY person_*->name ALPHA GET # GET "person_*->name" store list2
   ```
3. Remove all empty strings in *list1*, and get the number of elements removed: *num*:

   ```
   num = LREM list1 0 ""
   ```
4. Get the first `num * 2` elements from the *list2*:

   ```
   LRANGE list2 0 (num * 2 - 1)
   ```

**Explain:**

1. With the data sorted in lexicographically order, i.e. step 2, we can ensure that the non-existent members are in the front of the result list, i.e. *list2*, and the corresponding value is an empty string:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> lrange list2 0 -1
1) "6"
2) ""
3) "2"
4) "Mark"
5) "5"
6) "Robert"
```

2. We can remove all empty strings from *list1*, i.e. step 1 and step 3, so that we can get the number of members that doesn't exist in hash.

**NOTE**: we DO NOT sort in step 1 to save some cost.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> lrem list1 0 ""
(integer) 1
```

3. Then the first `num * 2` elements in *list2* is the result, i.e. step 4:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> lrange list2 0 1
1) "6"
2) ""
```

Comment: Hey thanks, the thought behind it is genius. Wouldn't have thought of that! Unfortunately, trying this, it seems that LREM can't filter for empty string:

`> LREM list1 0 ""
(error) ERR wrong number of arguments for 'lrem' command`

Comment: @blitter Are you trying this command with `redis-cli`? It should work, and works well with my Redis 5.0.5. Also you can try it with the official [redis demonstration](http://try.redis.io).

Comment: If you are using an unstable version of Redis, you might want to fire a bug to the community :)

Comment: Odd, odd. I am using redli; will test with redis-cli now. LREM list1 0 "somestring° works fine here, just not with empty string.

Comment: Ok it was redli. That goes right into the trash, thanks IBM. @for_stack your solution 100% works and is accepted! As for_stack stated, it's a bit of a "trick" based on the fact that nil is converted to the empty string when STOREd. If name were allowed to have empty strings, we'd have to choose a field that is guaranteed to be non-empty on non-orphaned records. Anyway, this 100% solves my problem which is to inform me which rows have been purged lately so I need to cache them again. Awesome! I need to rewire my brain to "think more like Redis"...